# How to send text from activity to fragment of other activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

> I've two activity "Name_Status" and "Main_activity".
>   In Main_activity , i've fragments . i wanna send a string value from Name_Status activity to one of Main_activity fragment.

Below  is the method  of Name_Status activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.ok_change_name)

    {
        name = name_change.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(name);
        Log.d("entered", "entred");
        MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
        Log.d("obj created", "obj created");
        obj.changeMainName(name);
        Log.d("obj.changename", "obj.changename");

    }
}
```

By using this method i'm first sending data to the Main_activity and from there sending data to fragment as below.

Below is the code of Main_activity:

```
public void changeMainName(String s) {
    FragActivity1 obj = (FragActivity1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.person_profile); obj.changeName(s); 
}
```

Now from here I'm sending string value to fragment class and there I'm only setting the string to the textview like below:

```
public void changeName(String s)
{

    Log.d("changename entry" ,"changename netry");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(name_field.getText().toString());
       name_field.setText(s);
    System.out.println(name_field.getText());
}
```

I'm getting

> NullPointerException at **obj.changeMainName(name);**

Comment: I think you are confused about java and Android , to send data to another Activivity android use the Intent , you can create a Intent and use the method putExtra() and at the activity that you will receive you data use getExtra()

Comment: you cannot new a activity, you should start a activity, then `ActivityManager` will be response for create the Activity instance and calls its lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send data to second activity by `Intent` bundle. Then get the data in second activity by `getIntent().getExtras()` and then pass the data to fragment.

Comment: i changed **MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();** and **obj.changeMainName(name); ** with **Intent obj =new Intent();
            obj.setClass(Name_Status.this,MainActivity.class);
            obj.putExtra("namekey","name");
            startActivity(obj);**

Comment: NullPointerException at obj.setClass(Name_Status.this,MainActivity.class);

Comment: Try this `Intent obj = new Intent(Name_Status.this, MainActivity.class);`

Answer (score 3):

You gonna have to do some relay. For instance you have activity A which has no Fragment and Activity B which has a fragment. On Android framework you can first pass data to From Activity A to B and From Activity B you can pass data to its Fragment following the view Hierarchy.

In Activity A. do the following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", "value");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Now inside Activity B, get data from activity A

```
String stringValue= getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Then pass that data your Fragment as an argument before to start Frag

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", stringValue);
    ActivityBFrag fragment =  new ActivityBFrag();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
```

Then inside your Fragment class. get data like below whenever you wanna access your data, can be inside onCreate, OnActivityCreated etc.

```
public void getArguments(){
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if(bundle != null){
        String stringValue = bundle.get("key");
    }
}
```

Comment: i just changed 'MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();obj.changeMainName(name);' with 'Intent obj =new Intent();
            obj.setClass(Name_Status.this,MainActivity.class);
            obj.putExtra("namekey","name");
            startActivity(obj);'

Comment: this time Nullpointer exception at obj.setClass(Name_Status.this,MainActivity.class);

Comment: Thats  not a good practice of passing data during runtime, It can cause a lot more issues than just simply NPE. Please follow the approach we have described above. its clean and safe, and off course you have to check for null values all the time.